# Google Cloud tesla K80, only one device showing up?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nvidia, tesla

I've setup an instance on Google Cloud with the following specs:
4 vCPUs, 15 GB memory, 1 Tesla K80 GPU

Tesla K80 consists of 2 GPU units and each should show up as a separate device in the nvidia's logs. However, when I run nvidia-smi in the shell it shows only one.
Image:
[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Is this because my cloud GPU quota is one and hence only one device is being used?

Additional logs:

```
==============NVSMI LOG==============

Timestamp                           : Tue Mar 13 16:05:42 2018
Driver Version                      : 390.30

Attached GPUs                       : 1
GPU 00000000:00:04.0
    Product Name                    : Tesla K80
    Product Brand                   : Tesla
    Display Mode                    : Disabled
    Display Active                  : Disabled
    Persistence Mode                : Disabled
    Accounting Mode                 : Disabled
    Accounting Mode Buffer Size     : 1920
    Driver Model
        Current                     : N/A
        Pending                     : N/A
    Serial Number                   : 0320717075175
    GPU UUID                        : GPU-a3a146ad-aed1-d5ef-1e76-2565c1e20a13
    Minor Number                    : 0
    VBIOS Version                   : 80.21.25.00.01
    MultiGPU Board                  : No
    Board ID                        : 0x4
    GPU Part Number                 : 900-22080-6300-001
    Inforom Version
        Image Version               : 2080.0200.00.04
        OEM Object                  : 1.1
        ECC Object                  : 3.0
        Power Management Object     : N/A
    GPU Operation Mode
        Current                     : N/A
        Pending                     : N/A
    GPU Virtualization Mode
        Virtualization mode         : Pass-Through
    PCI
        Bus                         : 0x00
        Device                      : 0x04
        Domain                      : 0x0000
        Device Id                   : 0x102D10DE
        Bus Id                      : 00000000:00:04.0
        Sub System Id               : 0x106C10DE
        GPU Link Info
            PCIe Generation
                Max                 : 3
                Current             : 3
            Link Width
                Max                 : 16x
                Current             : 16x
        Bridge Chip
            Type                    : N/A
            Firmware                : N/A
        Replays since reset         : 0
        Tx Throughput               : N/A
        Rx Throughput               : N/A
    Fan Speed                       : N/A
    Performance State               : P0
    Clocks Throttle Reasons
        Idle                        : Not Active
        Applications Clocks Setting : Active
        SW Power Cap                : Not Active
        HW Slowdown                 : Not Active
            HW Thermal Slowdown     : N/A
            HW Power Brake Slowdown : N/A
        Sync Boost                  : Not Active
        SW Thermal Slowdown         : Not Active
        Display Clock Setting       : Not Active
    FB Memory Usage
        Total                       : 11441 MiB
        Used                        : 10930 MiB
        Free                        : 511 MiB
    BAR1 Memory Usage
        Total                       : 16384 MiB
        Used                        : 3 MiB
        Free                        : 16381 MiB
    Compute Mode                    : Default
    Utilization
        Gpu                         : 54 %
        Memory                      : 1 %
        Encoder                     : 0 %
        Decoder                     : 0 %
    Encoder Stats
        Active Sessions             : 0
        Average FPS                 : 0
        Average Latency             : 0
    Ecc Mode
        Current                     : Enabled
        Pending                     : Enabled
    ECC Errors
        Volatile
            Single Bit            
                Device Memory       : 0
                Register File       : 0
                L1 Cache            : 0
                L2 Cache            : 0
                Texture Memory      : 0
                Texture Shared      : N/A
                CBU                 : N/A
                Total               : 0
            Double Bit            
                Device Memory       : 0
                Register File       : 0
                L1 Cache            : 0
                L2 Cache            : 0
                Texture Memory      : 0
                Texture Shared      : N/A
                CBU                 : N/A
                Total               : 0
        Aggregate
            Single Bit            
                Device Memory       : 0
                Register File       : 0
                L1 Cache            : 0
                L2 Cache            : 0
                Texture Memory      : 0
                Texture Shared      : N/A
                CBU                 : N/A
                Total               : 0
            Double Bit            
                Device Memory       : 7
                Register File       : 0
                L1 Cache            : 0
                L2 Cache            : 0
                Texture Memory      : 0
                Texture Shared      : N/A
                CBU                 : N/A
                Total               : 7
    Retired Pages
        Single Bit ECC              : 0
        Double Bit ECC              : 1
        Pending                     : No
    Temperature
        GPU Current Temp            : 56 C
        GPU Shutdown Temp           : 93 C
        GPU Slowdown Temp           : 88 C
        GPU Max Operating Temp      : N/A
        Memory Current Temp         : N/A
        Memory Max Operating Temp   : N/A
    Power Readings
        Power Management            : Supported
        Power Draw                  : 66.18 W
        Power Limit                 : 149.00 W
        Default Power Limit         : 149.00 W
        Enforced Power Limit        : 149.00 W
        Min Power Limit             : 100.00 W
        Max Power Limit             : 175.00 W
    Clocks
        Graphics                    : 562 MHz
        SM                          : 562 MHz
        Memory                      : 2505 MHz
        Video                       : 540 MHz
    Applications Clocks
        Graphics                    : 562 MHz
        Memory                      : 2505 MHz
    Default Applications Clocks
        Graphics                    : 562 MHz
        Memory                      : 2505 MHz
    Max Clocks
        Graphics                    : 875 MHz
        SM                          : 875 MHz
        Memory                      : 2505 MHz
        Video                       : 540 MHz
    Max Customer Boost Clocks
        Graphics                    : N/A
    Clock Policy
        Auto Boost                  : On
        Auto Boost Default          : On
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Digging through the cloud platform website, I found an answer to this. Instead of removing the question, I am leaving this here, in case someone else faces the same issue.

The Tesla K80 is '1 GPU board' consisting of 2 GPUs. If the number of GPUs on your VM instance on Google Cloud Platform is set to 1, you'd be allocated 1 GPU or half of a board.

[image]

Source: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/